# ASP.NET MVC 4, why custom engine doesn't find a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a class of custom view engine
and 2 engines derived from this class

```
public class MyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public string UIFramework { get; set; }

    public MyViewEngine(string uiFramework)
    {
        UIFramework = uiFramework;
        this.ViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.cshtml", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.vbhtml", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.aspx", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/{{1}}/{{0}}.ascx", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
        };
            this.PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.vbhtml", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.aspx", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.ascx", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
        };
        this.MasterLocationFormats = new[]
        {
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.vbhtml", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.aspx", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
            string.Format("~/Views/{0}/Shared/{{0}}.ascx", this.UIFramework ?? string.Empty),
        };

    }


}
```

and these 2 engines in Global.asax

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine("First"));
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new MyViewEngine("Second"));
```

there is no problem with finding views "under" Second view engine, but views "under" first aren't found. I can see that in ViewEngineResult searched locations are correct and Engine should see my view; and name of my view is correct too, but still ViewEngineResult returns null in View property.Folders structure are the same for both engines of course

Comment: Try to commented out the Second view engine in Global.asax and see the result

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for mistake, that was a problem with folder naming. Problem solved